# Issue in combining File List in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop, array-merge

Is it possible to merge FileList ?

For example say

```
arr_file1 = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files; // contains multiple files

arr_file2 = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files; //also contains multiple files
```

How to merge arr_file1 and arr_file2

as suggested by @ahgindia... out put:

First drag :

```
    FileList
0: File
lastModifiedDate: Fri May 09 2014 15:58:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
name: "netbeans-8.0-windows.exe"
size: 219347792
type: "application/x-msdownload"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
length: 1
__proto__: FileList
```

second drag after merging :

```
 [File, 1, function]
0: File
lastModifiedDate: Mon May 19 2014 09:25:30 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
name: "python-3.4.0.msi"
size: 24498176
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
1: 1
2: function item() { [native code] }
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: "item"
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply  merge two arrays, below is an example :

```
for(val in arr_file2) {
    arr_file1.push(arr_file2[val]);
}
console.log(arr_file1);
```

This will merge arr_file2 Filelist into arr_file1

Hope this helps you.

Comment: can you please give me output of arr_file1 and let me know what does not seems to be proper in output ?

Comment: check my updated question.. any douts in the updated questionm need any information

Answer (score 0):

I was actually with a similar problem, i needed the process to be faster than a "for" with the FileList.

At the end the solution was here [Merging/combining Filelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593963/merging-combining-filelist)
So hope this help a year later for future people with the same problem.