# Merging/combining Filelist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, filelist

I've got two Filelist objects containing multiple files  in a same form  and I want to merge it.

```
  var data1 = $('#one')[0].files;
  var data2 = $('#two')[0].files;
  console.log(data1);
  console.log(data2);
  var obj = $.merge(data1,data2);
  console.log(obj);
```

I tried `$.merge` and `$.extend`, the result obj seems have all the files, but the length of it is incorrect:

```
FileList {2: File, 3: File, 0: File, 1: File, length: 2}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nxtdnhgu/

Comment: `var obj = $.extend({}, data1, data2);` <-- what's the output for this?

Comment: @RazvanDumitru basically the same as $.merge:
`Object {0: File, 1: File, length: 1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jquery documentation.

The $.merge() function is destructive. It alters the length and numeric index properties of the first object to include items from the second.

If you need the original first array, make a copy of it before calling $.merge().

```
var obj = $.merge( $.merge( [], data1 ), data2 );
```

Working js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t1n08ykd/